# Change subscript position in any font size

Tags: math-mode, positioning, fontsize, subscripts

I'm using the `\fontdimen16\textfont2=5pt` to lower the position of a subscript. It works when the size of the font is normal, but nothing changes when I use one of the `\tiny, \small...\Huge` commands to change the size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\fontdimen16\textfont2=5pt
\[ c_5 \]
{\Huge \[ c_5 \]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there anything I can add so I can get it to work in all font sizes?

Comment: (i): $c_5^{}$, (ii): in preamble add `[low-sup]{subdepth}`.

Comment: it would work, but you have to do it again, as after `\Huge` textfont2 is a different, larger, font and you need to set the new font's parameter.

Comment: @David Carlisle How can I set this parameter? Will it change the subscript position globaly inside any document?